# Trouble uninstalling gem bundler

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm running the following software:
Ruby 2.3.3
Rails 4.2.10
Gem bundle 1.17.3 & 1.12.5

Git keeps defaulting to 1.17.3 but rails is only compatible with 1.12.5. I cannot uninstall 1.17.3 to use 1.12.5. Part of the problem is the gem uninstall bundler doesn't seem to be working - you still see it when do gem list bundler.

I don't want to update to a different version of Ruby or Rails. 
Any ideas?